# using on() jquery for dynamic content

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use on a dynamically added content and I'm not sure what I'm missing. I have two buttons one creates UL inside DIV. Then I click on another button to create LI inside the UL. On click on any of the LI i should get an alert message but nothing is happening!

http://jsfiddle.net/EkW63/

```
<div id='ok'></div>
<button id='fst'>create ul</button>
<button id='snd'>create li</button>

<script>
$("#fst").click(function(){
    $("#ok").html("<ul class='ul'></ul>");
});
$("#snd").click(function(){
    $(".ul").html("<li class='myclass'>one</li><li class='myclass'>two</li>");
});

$("ul").on('click', 'li.myclass', function(){ alert('ok'); });`
</script>
```

any suggestion?

Comment: `ul` itself is created dynamically, that means it doesn't even exist when you tried to call `on` on it.

Answer (score 2):

You should bind `on` with `#ok` div. Like this:

```
$("#ok").on('click', 'li.myclass', function(){ alert('ok'); });
```

Your `ul` is dynamically created as well so it will not work. `on` should be bound to elements that are already on the page when it loads.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li.myclass', function(){ 
    alert('ok'); 
});
```

Or even better ( opinion )

```
$("#fst").click(function(){
    $("#ok").html("<ul class='ul'></ul>");
});

var li = $("<li class='myclass'>one</li><li class='myclass'>two</li>");
$("#snd").click(function(){
    $(".ul").html(li);
});

li.on('click', function() {
   alert('hi');
});
```

For overall better code write all of like similar to this

```
$("#fst").click(function(){
    $("#ok").html('').append(
        $('<ul>', {'class': 'ul'})
    );
});

var li = $('<li>', {
    'class': 'myClass', 
    click: function() {
        alert('Hello');
    }
}),

$("#snd").click(function(){
    $(".ul").html('').append(li);
});
```

I use `append` because it's quicker, than `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dynamically creating the element, you need to bind the click event to the new element right after you created it, otherwise it won't work.